# Getting error for ManytoMany in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I am trying to validate, I am getting this error.

```
python manage.py validate
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 11, in <module>
    execute_manager(settings)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438, in execute_manager
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 191, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 220, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/validate.py", line 9, in handle_noargs
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 249, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 35, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 146, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 61, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 78, in load_app
    models = import_module('.models', app_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/google/Myfiles/cheeserater/../cheeserater/packages/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Package(models.Model):
  File "/usr/local/google/Myfiles/cheeserater/../cheeserater/packages/models.py", line 11, in Package
    categories = models.ManytoManyField(Category,related_name="packages")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'ManytoManyField'
```

Comment: models.Many*T*oManyField

Answer (score 20):

You have a typo:
categories = models.Many**T**oManyField

Answer (score -1):

You have a typo in **ManytoManyField**,
It should be **ManyToManyField**.

Comment: This was answered already back in 2011, with the exact same typo called out. The question itself should be closed (back in 2011 I don't believe there was a "caused by a typo" reason for closing, but it exists now). No need to post a duplicate answer, especially with a question almost a decade old...