# Django says "ManyToManyField" is not defined

Tags: django

I'm trying to use a ManytoManyField, but whenever I run makemigrations, Django returns this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/home/user/app/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/user/app/bin/app/app_main/models.py", line 7, in <module>
    class user(AbstractUser):
  File "/home/user/app/bin/app/app_main/models.py", line 8, in user
    blocking = models.ManytoManyField('self', symmetrical=False) 
AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'ManytoManyField'
```

Why is this happening? I have looked at other SO questions with similar issues, but they usually stem from the coder calling it "ManyToManyField" instead of "models.ManyToManyField". Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It is a `ManyToManyField` (with a capital `T` for `To`).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting error for ManytoMany in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5712221/getting-error-for-manytomany-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

You make typo here.
It should be

```
blocking = models.ManyToManyField('self', symmetrical=False)
```